# For-loop with multiprocessing in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, while-loop, multiprocessing

Here is the structure of the code snippet that creates the graph and meets certain conditions:

```
for i in range(1, len(binary_combinations)):

    # ...something          

    h=0
    while len(added)<i+1:   

         #...something  

         for j in it.combinations(good, 8):

             #...something

         h=h+1
```

Where `binary_combinations`, `added` and `good` they are some lists.
I'm trying to implement multiprocessing for it for the whole for loop. Or only for the function `it.combinations`, but to no avail, because I can not reconcile this with the execution of the while-loop.
How to approach it?

Comment: Before multiprocessing have you considered vectorizing your code?

Comment: I did not think about it because I'm not very good at vectorization yet. but if it would help, I will have to read more about it :)

Comment: secondly, I was interested in 'ordinary' loops because of the large number of values in the lists, so as not to remember the complete results in the operating memory.

Comment: Could you provide a reproducible example?

Comment: is an example of a complete code https://ufile.io/1v419

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as can be seen, you can abstract the first for loop easily:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool, cpu_count
import itertools as it

def foo(i):
    global added
    global good
    h=0
    while len(added)<i+1:   
        #...something  
        for j in it.combinations(good, 8):
            #...something
            h=h+1

pool = Pool(cpu_count())
results = pool.map(foo, range())
```

The main problem you will have here is that if you are mutating the lists inside your `#...something` code blocks it would be worthless, since the processes will not be sharing their stack state.